# Changing default confidence interval with stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer

I need to put in the same table two models in which in the second I need to change the default confidence interval. I know ci.custom option allows to change the default confidence interval but I would like to know how to change it only for the second model.

I tried including in the options something like this but didn't work.

```
stargazer(fit1,fit2, align=TRUE, ci=TRUE, ci.level=0.95, ci.custom=list(NULL, changed.ci))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way was to do the following:

```
ci.custom=list(confint(fit1), changed.ci)
```